# How to logout using NodeJs and end sessions

Tags: mysql, node.js, express, cookies

I have done this for now following some tutorials. The login part works fine. Cookies and sessions are created and all. But I can't kill the sessions for the logout button. Whenever I run this I get a 404 error. Uncaught (in promise) Error: Request failed with status code 404 What do I do here?

```
 const { loginStatus } = useContext(LoginContext);
    const logout = ()=>{
        Axios.get('http://localhost:3001/logout').then((response)=>{
            if(response){
                console.log(response)
            }
        })
    }
    return (
        <div>
            { loginStatus }
            <input type="submit" onClick={logout}/>
        </div>
    )
```

```
const express = require('express');
const mysql = require("mysql");
const cors = require('cors');

const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
const session = require('express-session');

const app = express();

app.use(express.json());
app.use(cors({
    origin: ['http://localhost:3000'],
    method: ["GET","POST"],
    credentials: true
}));

app.use(cookieParser());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }))

app.use(session({
    key: 'userId',
    secret: 'hello',
    resave: false,
    saveUninitialized: false,
    cookie:{
        expires: 60 * 60 * 24 * 1000,
    }
}))
.......
.....
app.get('/login',(req,res)=>{
    if(req.session.user){
        res.send({loggedIn: true, user: req.session.user})
    }
    else{
        res.send({loggedIn:false})
    }
})

app.get('/logout',(req,res) => {
    req.session.destroy();
    res.redirect('/');
});
app.listen(3001,()=>{
    console.log('running server');
})
```

Comment: "What do I do here?" I do not know what you are doing here, but some more debugging details would be nice....

Comment: I am making a login and logout system.. The login part is alright but I cant make the  logout

Comment: What exactly isn't working?  `req.session.destroy()` will destroy the current session object and any state it contains.  Of course, the very next request, express-session will create a new empty session object (that's what it always does).  For a technically accurate implementation, you should pass a callback to `req.session.destroy()` and call `res.redirect()` from within that callback so you're sure the session has been destroyed before you send the response.